# Android browser not respecting cookies disabled

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, android-browser

I am running Android Honeycomb 3.2.1 and I am having trouble getting the browser to stop accepting cookies. I have the following code:

first.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setCookie('testing','test cookie',365);
            window.location.href = 'second.html';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

second.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var temp = getCookie('testing');
            alert(temp);
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

cookie.js:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";     expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now if I shut off cookies and visit first.html on any of my desktop browsers, I get redirected and get an alert that says null as expected.

If I turn on my cookies and visit first.html on any of my desktop browsers, I get redirected and get an alert that says "test cookie" as expected.

Now if I run this on my Android tablet with cookies disabled it always returns "test cookie" in an alert. It doesn't matter if I have cookies on or off. I have tried changing the settings, removing the cookies and cache, restarting the browser and even restarted the tablet and all with the same results.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same problem - we ended up checking cookies on the server and returning an HTTP error code if cookies were not set.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking it with server side code. For e.g if you were using JSP. You could do this inside your onLoad or $(document).ready(){}:

```
<%
            String cookieAllowed = "false";
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie ("username","value");
            cookie.setMaxAge(365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
            response.addCookie(cookie);

            String cookieName = "username";
            Cookie cookies [] = request.getCookies ();
            Cookie myCookie = null;
            if (cookies != null)
            {
                //If true then cookies are not null
                cookieAllowed = "true";
            }
            %>

            if(! <%=cookieAllowed%>)
            {
                window.location = "/static/nocookies.html"; 
            }
%>
```

I am sure other server side scripts should also work.